# What is QtCore.pyqtSlot before the slot function good for?

Tags: python, pyqt5, slot

In some code I review I see a line

```
QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
```

or

```
@QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
```

before the definition of the function that is the slot function and connected to a signal.
I have always worked without that line. So what is it good for? How is the syntax, @ or not, use of str...

Thanks for any help

Comment: @mikuszefski Thanks for the link. Yes it answers the questions.

Comment: here is the latest PyQt doc on this:
https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#the-pyqtslot-decorator